# Aspose-Cells: How do I evaluate a formula?

Tags: aspose, aspose-cells

Given the following code:

```
using Aspose.Cells
// {...}  
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();  
Worksheet virtualWorksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];  
virtualWorksheet.Cells[0, 0].Formula ="=1<2";
```

How do I evaluate the formula in Cell [0,0]?

```
bool isCellTrue = virtualWorksheet.Cells[0, 0].BoolValue; // will generate an exception at run-time
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/permalink/212217/212232/showthread.aspx#212232

Call Workbook.CalculateFormula() method to calculate all the formulas in the workbook before getting/retrieving the calculated value at runtime, e.g.

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook(); 
Worksheet virtualWorksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0]; 
virtualWorksheet.Cells[0, 0].Formula ="=1<2";
workbook.CalculateFormula(); 
bool isCellTrue = virtualWorksheet.Cells[0, 0].BoolValue;
```